# SSL Certificate: How to accommodate short name?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

If the server has FQDN as its certificate common name (no alternative name used), is there a way to access it with short name without causing certificate verification error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no.
If the the the fqdn is www.example.com, the certificate is for www.example.com and no other names, but you access it as example.com, you will get a certificate error because the names do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new web cert with some additional SANS (Server Alternate Names). Details see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krd9ZsJCZ6s